# Can the emacs shell do prompt completion like zsh?

Tags: emacs, zsh

I'm a newbie to emacs, and I know that zsh can be called from the M-x shell in emacs, but zsh on emacs doesn't have prompt-completion anymore, and I'm wondering if there's a way to fix it, or if there's any other way to get prompt-completion in the emacs shell (which doesn't apply to zsh as well)
My zsh configuration is the manjaro default configuration.

I would like to have the part with the gray font
[image]
This is not available in the emacs shell.
[image]
Also, are there any plugins in emacs that would make using the emacs shell closer to normal zsh? It's a bit uncomfortable not being able to use the up and down keys to find the history.

Comment: check out vterm, https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm. That's the closest you'll get

Comment: Check out Emacs' [`ansi-term`](https://gitlab.com/yugaego/emacs-config/-/blob/main/configs/init-shell.el?ref_type=heads#L35). Works like a charm for me with *fish* shell. And there's a number of related discussions here and on Emacs SE worth looking into.

Comment: If you know the emacs keys, ^p, ^n for next and prev, (rather than arrows), then they become M-p and M-n in shell mode. Everything normally C- becomes M-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [esh-autosuggest](https://github.com/dieggsy/esh-autosuggest) package should give you this type of suggestions in eshell.